# Do the self-similarities of a fractal function govern its convergence properties?

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, collatz-conjecture, iterated-function-system

Let the graph of a function take a fractal form, such as the following representation of the Collatz conjecture topologically conjugated to the interval $[\frac12,1)\to[\frac12,1)$

[image: COllatz Conjecture Fractal]

In this example, the top and bottom of the map are equivalent - fine, we can think of the function acting on a hollow cylinder with no ends.  Left and right are also equivalent - fine, we get a Torus.

And there is what I'm going to call a singularity at $\frac23$ where the function maps to $0$, which is off the graph.  I mention the singularity, because one of the function's self-similarities which you can clearly see is that the interval $[\frac34,1)$ is equal to the interval one quarter its size and immediately to its left.  That repeats and converges to the singularity.

**Question**

Are there theorems about functions represented by 2d fractals, such as e.g. Sierpinski's triangle, and under what circumstances they converge (when iterated)?  In particular, I'm interested in relationships between the self-similarities of the fractal and convergence.

**My Thoughts**

Intuitively, I can see an obvious opportunity - mod/quotient out symmetries to find a structure which is well-founded, and show that function iteration descends the well-founded structure.  Is this and/or other formulised somewhere so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Hmm, nice picture, didn't see such an image in context with the Collatz-problem before. But I might misunderstand your concept of making a hollow cyclinder resp. torus. I copied the picture to its left and this then to its bottom, and got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38kLy.png . The upper and lower border seem not to fit, so I seem to have misunderstood you. Could you please explain again?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms you seem to have glued it correctly and therefore understood the cylinder / torus point.  The step change from $y=1$ to $y=\frac12$ is just a repetition of the step changes occurring at other isometries of $y$.  In this graph $\frac12\sim1$.  Also, the left hand third is a scale copy of the right hand two thirds so if you had scaled it accordingly, the symmetries would be more apparent.